# How do I delete table but keep the data in trino?

Tags: trino

I am wondering if it's possible to remove a table from trino, but keep it's data. I'm interested in this feature for hive and iceberg connectors specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do if you use hive metastore (like in my case).

We need to set the table in hive as external `ALTER TABLE schema.table SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE')`, using hive, and then, through hive, drop it.